# How do i trigger Autosys CA for deploying JIL files via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, autosys

Could you please suggest how to trigger autosys CA workload automation from JenkinsI need to deploy the jobs on CA AutoSys. Appreciate the response .Thanks

Comment: Do u have modify / admin / write access to the Autosys Instance thru CLI ?

Comment: Thanks @Piyush for your response. I have access to Autosys CA portal & have read/write access

Comment: Assuming you the end user of Autosys and not the part of Autosys Admin, First check with admin if they allow remote CLI access to the Autosys Instance. If yes ask for the "iXp Client Command Line Interface" file and then further path and variable configurations

Comment: 1. get the ixp.tar 2. Untar at $HOME (~) 3. Update unix user .profile with path of ~/ixp/ect/ixp.profile 4. update ~/ixp/ect/ixp.conf with the URL to access Autosys  (these are generic steps to install package in Linux server and might differ)

Comment: sure Thank you let me check on that. Is that remote CLI access to Autosys mandatory  ? basically i need to trigger autosys from Jenkins  thinking if there is any Plugin available within jenkins to do so

Comment: As per my findings I couldn't find Autosys plugin, so suggested this way.